# git: .git/refs/remotes/origin/master doesn't exist. Why does git checkout refs/heads/origin/master work?

Tags: git

As mentioned above

```
.git/refs/remotes/origin/master
```

does not exist but

```
.git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
```

does and it contains

```
ref: refs/remotes/origin/master
```

So the HEAD ref is referring non-existent ref in my tree. Nonetheless, both `git checkout refs/remotes/origin/master` and `git checkout refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` work and checkout the expected commit.

Where is git getting this metadata from if it's not in the refs directory?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+.git%2Frefs%2Fremotes%2Forigin%2Fmaster+doesn%27t+exist